# How to Resize sheet in ExpressSCH?

Tags: circuit

I have created a large schematic. It is larger than the default page size in ExpressSCH. I would like to resize the page boundaries to fit. How do you do this?

There is a rectangle around the sheet, with small squares on each corner. I need to resize this! I would guess that you click on one of the small squares, or navigate the menus to achieve this, but that does not work. There is also no web-searchable directions.

How do you resize the page / change the outer rectangles size?

Answer (score 2):

Select the page tab you're trying to resize, go to "Page size" item in the "File" menu. This gives you a list of available standard sizes such as letter, tabloid, A4 sizes. Once selected, the page will be expanded/shrunk to selected size.